# Django The request's session was deleted before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a concurrent request, for example

Tags: mysql, django, session

When I try To log in with my user ID on the server this message will raise. But The same database in my local PC is ok its login successfully.

> SuspiciousOperation at /loginCheck The request's session was deleted
>   before the request completed. The user may have logged out in a
>   concurrent request, for example.

also here is that error page pic

[image]

I do a few google searches but not working out.

I'm using Django 2.1
and my database is MySQL